# Sort List<String> based on date

Tags: java, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a `List<String>` based on its date. The list:

```
[
    datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0057c620ea6040849da9bceb977e7332-2023-09-11-19-30-10-00445.txt,
    datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_00e1cd4e425243bda8e09ee2b7b2334f-2023-09-11-19-30-02-00554.txt,
    datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_021b63466ff6406d8b30b25bda63b49f-2023-09-11-19-30-21-00218.txt,
    datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_049a681a00214155b7dab7c94c871341-2023-09-11-19-30-15-00036.txt,
    datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_068e490f3b78453293e84bdfb49112ad-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00288.txt,
    datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0694fca541d0486689c6591b16cb1fbc-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00405.txt,
    datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0a8d4975741e4b088ead2bfd1edee1ad-2023-09-11-19-30-07-00188.txt
]
```

The section I want to sort based is:

```
2023-09-11-19-30-10-00445
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    private static final String REGEX = "-(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{5})\\.txt$";
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSSSS", Locale.ENGLISH);

    private static int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        Matcher m1 = PATTERN.matcher(s1);
        m1.find();
        LocalDateTime ts1 = LocalDateTime.parse(m1.group(1), FORMATTER);
        Matcher m2 = PATTERN.matcher(s2);
        m2.find();
        LocalDateTime ts2 = LocalDateTime.parse(m2.group(1), FORMATTER);
        return ts1.isAfter(ts2) ? 1 : ts1.isBefore(ts2) ? -1 : 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Comparator<String> c = Main::compare;
        List<String> tmp = List.of("datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0057c620ea6040849da9bceb977e7332-2023-09-11-19-30-10-00445.txt",
                                   "datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_00e1cd4e425243bda8e09ee2b7b2334f-2023-09-11-19-30-02-00554.txt",
                                   "datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_021b63466ff6406d8b30b25bda63b49f-2023-09-11-19-30-21-00218.txt",
                                   "datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_049a681a00214155b7dab7c94c871341-2023-09-11-19-30-15-00036.txt",
                                   "datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_068e490f3b78453293e84bdfb49112ad-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00288.txt",
                                   "datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0694fca541d0486689c6591b16cb1fbc-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00405.txt",
                                   "datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0a8d4975741e4b088ead2bfd1edee1ad-2023-09-11-19-30-07-00188.txt");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(tmp);
        Collections.sort(list, c);
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

The above code implements a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) to sort the list.
The `Comparator` uses [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) to extract the relevant part of each string in the list.
It then converts that extracted string to [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) in order to determine the chronological order.

Note that the first line in method `main`, i.e.

```java
Comparator<String> c = Main::compare;
```

is a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Here is the output when I run the above code:

```
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_00e1cd4e425243bda8e09ee2b7b2334f-2023-09-11-19-30-02-00554.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0a8d4975741e4b088ead2bfd1edee1ad-2023-09-11-19-30-07-00188.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0057c620ea6040849da9bceb977e7332-2023-09-11-19-30-10-00445.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_068e490f3b78453293e84bdfb49112ad-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00288.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0694fca541d0486689c6591b16cb1fbc-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00405.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_049a681a00214155b7dab7c94c871341-2023-09-11-19-30-15-00036.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_021b63466ff6406d8b30b25bda63b49f-2023-09-11-19-30-21-00218.txt
```

Comment: Hello thanky ou for your response. 
Can you please explain the logic for 
`return ts1.isAfter(ts2) ? 1 : ts1.isBefore(ts2) ? -1 : 0;` ?
@Abra

Comment: @NoobCoder did you read the documentation for interface `Comparator` that I linked to in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

A one-liner:

```java
"[datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0057c620ea6040849da9bceb977e7332-2023-09-11-19-30-10-00445.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_00e1cd4e425243bda8e09ee2b7b2334f-2023-09-11-19-30-02-00554.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_021b63466ff6406d8b30b25bda63b49f-2023-09-11-19-30-21-00218.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_049a681a00214155b7dab7c94c871341-2023-09-11-19-30-15-00036.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_068e490f3b78453293e84bdfb49112ad-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00288.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0694fca541d0486689c6591b16cb1fbc-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00405.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0a8d4975741e4b088ead2bfd1edee1ad-2023-09-11-19-30-07-00188.txt]"
        .replace ( "[" , "" )
        .replace ( "]" , "" )
        .replace ( ", " , "\n" )
        .lines ( )
        .sorted (
                Comparator.comparing ( ( String s ) -> s.substring (
                        "datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0057c620ea6040849da9bceb977e7332-".length ( ) ,
                        "datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0057c620ea6040849da9bceb977e7332-2023-09-11-19-30-10-00445".length ( )
                ) )
        )
        .forEach ( System.out :: println );
```

```
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_00e1cd4e425243bda8e09ee2b7b2334f-2023-09-11-19-30-02-00554.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0a8d4975741e4b088ead2bfd1edee1ad-2023-09-11-19-30-07-00188.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0057c620ea6040849da9bceb977e7332-2023-09-11-19-30-10-00445.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_068e490f3b78453293e84bdfb49112ad-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00288.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0694fca541d0486689c6591b16cb1fbc-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00405.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_049a681a00214155b7dab7c94c871341-2023-09-11-19-30-15-00036.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_021b63466ff6406d8b30b25bda63b49f-2023-09-11-19-30-21-00218.txt
```

### Details

Massage the input. Remove the brackets. Replace each COMMA+SPACE delimiter with LINEFEED character.

```java
String input = "[datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0057c620ea6040849da9bceb977e7332-2023-09-11-19-30-10-00445.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_00e1cd4e425243bda8e09ee2b7b2334f-2023-09-11-19-30-02-00554.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_021b63466ff6406d8b30b25bda63b49f-2023-09-11-19-30-21-00218.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_049a681a00214155b7dab7c94c871341-2023-09-11-19-30-15-00036.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_068e490f3b78453293e84bdfb49112ad-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00288.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0694fca541d0486689c6591b16cb1fbc-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00405.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0a8d4975741e4b088ead2bfd1edee1ad-2023-09-11-19-30-07-00188.txt]";
String modified =
        input
                .replace ( "[" , "" )
                .replace ( "]" , "" )
                .replace ( ", " , "\n" );
```

Parse the modified string as lines, breaking on each LINEFEED.

```java
List < String > lines =
        modified
                .lines ( )
                .toList ( );
```

That results in an unmodifiable list. To sort we need to make a modifiable list.

```java
lines = new ArrayList <> ( lines ); // Make unmodifiable list modifiable.
```

Sort the collection of lines by specifying a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html). Our comparator pulls your date-time text as a substring. All your lines have the same length, so we can easily determine the starting and ending index of the character positions we want to extract for sorting.

No need to parse as a date-time; your text in alphabetical order is also in chronological order.

```java
int indexStart = "datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0057c620ea6040849da9bceb977e7332-".length ( );
int indexEnd = indexStart + "2023-09-11-19-30-10-00445".length ( );
Comparator < String > comparator = Comparator.comparing ( ( String s ) -> s.substring ( indexStart , indexEnd ) );
```

Pass the comparator to the [`List#sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)) method.

```java
lines.sort ( comparator );
```

Done.

Here is the complete example code, including some code for dumping the data to console.

```java
public class SortingEmbedded
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        String input = "[datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0057c620ea6040849da9bceb977e7332-2023-09-11-19-30-10-00445.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_00e1cd4e425243bda8e09ee2b7b2334f-2023-09-11-19-30-02-00554.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_021b63466ff6406d8b30b25bda63b49f-2023-09-11-19-30-21-00218.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_049a681a00214155b7dab7c94c871341-2023-09-11-19-30-15-00036.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_068e490f3b78453293e84bdfb49112ad-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00288.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0694fca541d0486689c6591b16cb1fbc-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00405.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0a8d4975741e4b088ead2bfd1edee1ad-2023-09-11-19-30-07-00188.txt]";
        String modified =
                input
                        .replace ( "[" , "" )
                        .replace ( "]" , "" )
                        .replace ( ", " , "\n" );
        List < String > lines =
                modified
                        .lines ( )
                        .toList ( );
        lines = new ArrayList <> ( lines ); // Make unmodifiable list modifiable.

        // Report before sorting.
        System.out.println ( "------------\nlines BEFORE sort = " );
        lines.forEach ( System.out :: println );
        System.out.println ( "------------" );

        // Sort
        int indexStart = "datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0057c620ea6040849da9bceb977e7332-".length ( );
        int indexEnd = indexStart + "2023-09-11-19-30-10-00445".length ( );
        Comparator < String > comparator = Comparator.comparing ( ( String s ) -> s.substring ( indexStart , indexEnd ) );
        lines.sort ( comparator );

        // Report after sorting.
        System.out.println ( "------------\nlines AFTER sort = " );
        lines.forEach ( System.out :: println );
        System.out.println ( "------------" );


        // Dump data.
        for ( String line : lines )
        {
            System.out.println ( line.substring ( indexStart , indexEnd ) );
        }
        System.out.println ( "------------\ninput = \n" + input );
        System.out.println ( "------------\nmodified = \n" + modified );
        System.out.println ( "------------\n" );
    }
}
```

When run:

```
------------
lines BEFORE sort = 
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0057c620ea6040849da9bceb977e7332-2023-09-11-19-30-10-00445.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_00e1cd4e425243bda8e09ee2b7b2334f-2023-09-11-19-30-02-00554.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_021b63466ff6406d8b30b25bda63b49f-2023-09-11-19-30-21-00218.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_049a681a00214155b7dab7c94c871341-2023-09-11-19-30-15-00036.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_068e490f3b78453293e84bdfb49112ad-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00288.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0694fca541d0486689c6591b16cb1fbc-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00405.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0a8d4975741e4b088ead2bfd1edee1ad-2023-09-11-19-30-07-00188.txt
------------
------------
lines AFTER sort = 
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_00e1cd4e425243bda8e09ee2b7b2334f-2023-09-11-19-30-02-00554.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0a8d4975741e4b088ead2bfd1edee1ad-2023-09-11-19-30-07-00188.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0057c620ea6040849da9bceb977e7332-2023-09-11-19-30-10-00445.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_068e490f3b78453293e84bdfb49112ad-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00288.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0694fca541d0486689c6591b16cb1fbc-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00405.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_049a681a00214155b7dab7c94c871341-2023-09-11-19-30-15-00036.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_021b63466ff6406d8b30b25bda63b49f-2023-09-11-19-30-21-00218.txt
------------
2023-09-11-19-30-02-00554
2023-09-11-19-30-07-00188
2023-09-11-19-30-10-00445
2023-09-11-19-30-14-00288
2023-09-11-19-30-14-00405
2023-09-11-19-30-15-00036
2023-09-11-19-30-21-00218
------------
input = 
[datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0057c620ea6040849da9bceb977e7332-2023-09-11-19-30-10-00445.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_00e1cd4e425243bda8e09ee2b7b2334f-2023-09-11-19-30-02-00554.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_021b63466ff6406d8b30b25bda63b49f-2023-09-11-19-30-21-00218.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_049a681a00214155b7dab7c94c871341-2023-09-11-19-30-15-00036.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_068e490f3b78453293e84bdfb49112ad-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00288.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0694fca541d0486689c6591b16cb1fbc-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00405.txt, datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0a8d4975741e4b088ead2bfd1edee1ad-2023-09-11-19-30-07-00188.txt]
------------
modified = 
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0057c620ea6040849da9bceb977e7332-2023-09-11-19-30-10-00445.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_00e1cd4e425243bda8e09ee2b7b2334f-2023-09-11-19-30-02-00554.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_021b63466ff6406d8b30b25bda63b49f-2023-09-11-19-30-21-00218.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_049a681a00214155b7dab7c94c871341-2023-09-11-19-30-15-00036.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_068e490f3b78453293e84bdfb49112ad-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00288.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0694fca541d0486689c6591b16cb1fbc-2023-09-11-19-30-14-00405.txt
datareplay/upstream/20230911/2023-09-11/WIRE_ISSN.WIRE_CRTD_0a8d4975741e4b088ead2bfd1edee1ad-2023-09-11-19-30-07-00188.txt
------------
```

Answer (score 0):

1. copy the alpha-numeric characters that are part of the date you want to sort by to the front of each string
2. sort them using the default method for sorting strings
3. then delete the characters you just added

note: using the Stream class is helpful

You said you are using a list but in case you meant an array I will include the code for both

if you storing your data using List list:

```
    list=list.stream().map(i->(i.substring(93,118).replaceAll("-", "")+i)).sorted().map(i->i.substring(19)).toList();
```

if you storing your data using String[] array:

```
array=(String[])Arrays.stream(array).map(i->(i.substring(93,118).replaceAll("-", "")+i)).sorted().map(i->i.substring(19)).toArray(String[]::new);
```